# Cannot rename directory powershell

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, command-line, filesystems

I have a powershell script that copies folders to a new directory and then renames that new directory based on the current date.  The copying function works great however I get the following error message when it goes to rename the directory:

```
Rename-Item : Access to the path '\\DPR320-W12-1600\PRTG\6212016 backup' is denied.
```

I think this might be due to the copying that is taking place right before that line is executed because I do not get that error message when that command is run by itself.  Would there be a way that I could rename the folder immediately after the copying finishes? Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have pasted the script below in its entirety.

```
$targetdirectory = "\\DPR320-W12-1600\PRTG"
$sourcedirectory = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\PRTG Traffic Grapher"
$todaysdate=get-date
$minusoneweek=$todaysdate.adddays(-7)
$minusdate=($minusoneweek.Month).tostring(),($minusoneweek.day).tostring(),($minusoneweek.year).tostring()
$todaysdatestring=($todaysdate.Month).tostring(),($todaysdate.day).tostring(),($todaysdate.year).tostring()
$oldfilename=$minusdate[0]+$minusdate[1]+$minusdate[2]+" backup"
$newfilename=$todaysdatestring[0]+$todaysdatestring[1]+$todaysdatestring[2]+" backup"
$Threshold = (get-date).AddMonths(-18)
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$count=0


Get-ChildItem $sourcedirectory\config | Where-Object { 
    $_.PsIsContainer -and 
    $_.BaseName -match '\d{6}' -and 
    ([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName, 'yyyyMMdd', $null) -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) 
} |Copy-Item -Recurse -Force -Destination $targetdirectory\$oldfilename\config

Copy-Item -Force $sourcedirectory\config.csv -Destination $targetdirectory\$oldfilename
Copy-Item -Force $sourcedirectory\config.prtg -Destination $targetdirectory\$oldfilename

rename-item $targetdirectory\$oldfilename $newfilename

$CleanupList = Get-ChildItem $targetdirectory\$newfilename\config

foreach ($DirName in $CleanupList)
{
try {
  If([datetime]::ParseExact($DirName.BaseName, 'yyyyMMdd', $culture) -lt $Threshold)

{
    write-host [datetime]::ParseExact($DirName.BaseName, 'yyyyMMdd', $culture)
  #Remove-Item $DirName.FullName -Force -Recurse

}

Write-Host $count
$count=$count+1

}


catch {

Write-Host $count
$count=$count+1

  continue
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in a while loop that will try to rename the file until it is successful:

```
while($true){
    try {
        rename-item $targetdirectory\$oldfilename $newfilename -ErrorAction Stop
        # It will only reach the break statement if rename-item was successful
        # The break statement will exit the while loop
        break
    }
    catch {
        write-host "couldn't rename file..."
        start-sleep -s 1
    }
}
```

You might want to also add a counter and break if it isn't successful after *n* attempts.  Otherwise it might end up retrying on a file infinitely if something unexpected opens the file and holds it open or denies access, such as antivirus blocking it, etc.